# How to solve the differential equation $(x^{2}t(x)^{2n} - 1)nt(x)^{n-1}dt + 2xt(x)^{3n}dx = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation $(x^{2}t(x)^{2n} - 1)nt(x)^{n-1}dt + 2xt(x)^{3n}dx = 0$

I guess it should become something like $x^{2}t(x)^{2n} + ct(x)^{n} + 1 = 0$ (c is a constant) but I don't know how to make it.

Any ideas?

Comment: A series solution or laplace transform would seem applicable here.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: change of variables $y = t^n$.

EDIT: That makes the differential equation into 
$$(y^2 x^2 - 1)\; dy + 2 x y^3\; dx = 0 $$
If $N = y^2 x^2 - 1$ and $M = 2 x y^3$, we have 
$$\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x} = 2 x y^2, \ \dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y} = 6 x y^2$$
Since $$\dfrac{\partial N/\partial x - \partial M/\partial y}{M} =  -\dfrac{2}{y}$$
is a function of $y$ only, there is an integrating factor $\mu(y)$ that is a function of $y$, and it can be obtained by solving
$$ \mu'(y) = \dfrac{\partial N/\partial x - \partial M/\partial y}{M} \mu(y)$$

Comment: Could you tell me what to do next? That's where I'm stuck :)

Comment: Original problem had y and required to use $t=y^n$